# Issue with aligning DropdownMenu just above BottomBar in Scaffold

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm currently working on a Jetpack Compose screen where I have a Scaffold containing a BottomBar. Within this setup, I'm attempting to show a DropdownMenu just above the BottomBar when a button within the BottomBar is clicked.

I've tried to implement this functionality, but I'm encountering unexpected UI behavior where the DropdownMenu appears above the BottomBar with some weird space.

[Unexpected behaviors' of UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QdyC.png)

My Code is

```
@Composable
private fun CustomBottomBar(
    allSendersContactMethod: List<String>,
    presenter: NewConversationPresenter,
    selectedContacts: List<selectedContact>,
) {
    var expanded: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedSenderContactMethod by remember { mutableStateOf("Select a method") }
    var hasSelected: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 14.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
    ) {
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            allSendersContactMethod.forEach { contactMethod ->
                DropdownMenuItem(text = {
                    Text(text = contactMethod)
                }, onClick = {
                    selectedSenderContactMethod = contactMethod
                    hasSelected = true
                    expanded = false
                },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }
        }

        Text(
            text = selectedSenderContactMethod,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .clickable {
                    expanded = true
                }
                .border(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, shape = CircleShape)
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 6.dp)
        )

        if (hasSelected) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            IconButton(
                onClick = { presenter.onCreateButtonClick(recipients = selectedContacts, senderContactMethod = selectedSenderContactMethod) },
                modifier = Modifier.background(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Send, contentDescription = "Create thread button", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Scaffold code is

```
Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            CustomNewConversationTopAppBar(
                                title = NewConversationScreen.TOP_APP_BAR_TITLE,
                                onBackClick = { onBackPressesDispatcher?.onBackPressed() },
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp),
                                textFieldValue = toTextFieldValue,
                                onToTextFieldChange = {
                                    toTextFieldValue = it
                                },
                                selectedContacts = selectedContacts,
                                presenter = newConversationPresenter
                            )
                        },
                        bottomBar = {
                            if (selectedContacts.isNotEmpty()) {
                                CustomBottomBar(
                                    allSendersContactMethod = allSendersContactMethod,
                                   selectedContacts = selectedContacts.toList(),
                                    presenter = newConversationPresenter,
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(
                                    top = it.calculateTopPadding(),
                                    bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding(),
                                ),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                        ) {
                            ContactListUI(
                                contactList = contactsList,
                                onContactProfileClick = { contact ->
                                    newConversationPresenter.onNewContactAddFromContactList(
                                        selectedContact(
                                            recipient = contact.name,
                                            contactMethod = contact.phoneNumber
                                        )
                                    )
                                })

                        }
                    }"
```

I have tried to put the DropDown menu in Scaffold's Main screen but now DropDown menu appears at the top left corner with some padding from the top and left, instead of aligning at the bottom.

Scaffold code is:

```
Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            CustomNewConversationTopAppBar(
                                title = NewConversationScreen.TOP_APP_BAR_TITLE,
                                onBackClick = { onBackPressesDispatcher?.onBackPressed() },
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp),
                                textFieldValue = toTextFieldValue,
                                onToTextFieldChange = {
                                    toTextFieldValue = it
                                },
                                selectedContacts = selectedContacts,
                                presenter = newConversationPresenter
                            )
                        },
                        bottomBar = {
                            if (selectedContacts.isNotEmpty()) {
                                CustomBottomBar(
//                                    allSendersContactMethod = allSendersContactMethod,
                                   selectedContacts = selectedContacts.toList(),
                                    presenter = newConversationPresenter,
                                    selectedSenderContactMethod = selectedSenderContactMethod,
                                    hasSelected = hasSelected,
                                    onSelectContactMethodClick = {
                                        expanded = true
//                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(
                                    top = it.calculateTopPadding(),
                                    bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding(),
                                ),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                        ) {
                            ContactListUI(
                                contactList = contactsList,
                                onContactProfileClick = { contact ->
                                    newConversationPresenter.onNewContactAddFromContactList(
                                        selectedContact(
                                            recipient = contact.name,
                                            contactMethod = contact.phoneNumber
                                        )
                                    )
                                })
                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = expanded,
                                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                                offset = DpOffset(100.dp, 100.dp)
                            ) {
                                allSendersContactMethod.forEach { contactMethod ->
                                    DropdownMenuItem(text = {
                                        Text(text = contactMethod)
                                    }, onClick = {
                                        selectedSenderContactMethod = contactMethod
                                        hasSelected = true
                                        expanded = false
                                    },
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And custombar code:

```
@Composable
private fun CustomBottomBar(
    presenter: NewConversationPresenter,
    selectedContacts: List<selectedContact>,
    selectedSenderContactMethod: String,
    onSelectContactMethodClick: () -> Unit,
    hasSelected: Boolean
) {
    var expanded: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedSenderContactMethod by remember { mutableStateOf("Select a method") }
    var hasSelected: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 14.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
    ) {

        Text(
            text = selectedSenderContactMethod,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .clickable {
                    onSelectContactMethodClick()
                }
                .border(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, shape = CircleShape)
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 6.dp)
        )

        if (hasSelected) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            IconButton(
                onClick = { presenter.onCreateButtonClick(recipients = selectedContacts, senderContactMethod = selectedSenderContactMethod) },
                modifier = Modifier.background(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Send, contentDescription = "Create thread button", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
            }
        }
    }

}
```